# Handling Type Error for Database-Generated Fields in Python API Application

Tags: python, sql, database, types

I have a Python application with an API that interacts with a SQL database. The API allows users to perform various operations, and the results are stored in the database. I'm currently facing an issue related to a type error that is raised when using a field generated by the database.

In this model, certain fields are generated by the database, and when attempting to use them in the API operations, a type error is raised. I understand that one solution is to create two separate models for Threshold object. One for saving and one for retrieval, but this approach seems to introduce a significant amount of additional code for what appears to be a relatively small feature.

Here's a simplified example of my current code:
SQL schema

```
Threshold:
    id: int
    value: int
    created_on: datetime now() not null
    
ObjectB:
    id: int
    inputted_field: str
    calculated_field: int
    FOREIGN KEY (threshold_id) REFERENCES Threshold(id)
```

Python data schema

```
@dataclass
class Threshold:
    value: int
    created_on: datetime | None = None
    
@dataclass
class ObjectB:
    inputted_field: str
    calculated_field: int
    threshold: Threshold
```

Python data access

```
class MyRepository:
    def add_threshold(threshold: Threshold):
        # sql insert in which created_on field is set by DB
        
    def add_object_b(object_b: ObjectB):
        # sql insert
        
    def get_all_thresholds() -> list[Threshold]: # this thresholds have created_on != None
        # sql select
```

API Module

```
my_repository = MyRepository()

def add_threshold(value: int):
    my_threshold = Threshold(value=value)
    my_repository.add_threshold(my_threshold) # this threshold had created_on == None

def optionally_add_object_b(inputted_field: str):
    my_objects_a = my_repostiory.get_all_objects_thresholds(value=value)
    newest_threshold = max(objects_a, key=lambda x: x.created_on)
    
    my_object_b = create_object_b(inputted_field=inputted_field, threshold=threshold)
    if my_object_b.calculated_field > newest_threshold.value:
        my_repository.add_object_b(my_object_b)
    
def do_operation_on_thresholds():
    my_thresholds = my_repository.get_all_thresholds()
    # This next line raises type error
    my_threshold_dates = [threshold.created_on.date for threshold in my_thresholds] 
    ...
```

Functions used in API

```
def create_object_b(inputted_field: str, threshold: Threshold) -> ObjectB:
    calculated_field = my_complicated_operation_on_threshold(threshold)
    return ObjectB(inputted_field=inputted_field, calculated_field=calculated_field)
    
def my_complicated_operation_on_threshold(treshold: Threshold) -> int:
    # do some complicated operation on threshold
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle this type error more elegantly and make the model easier to use. Are there any design patterns or best practices that can be applied to streamline this process?
I asked my teamates how to do it, but their suggestions added a lot of extra code.

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!